# hard coded text with user input in include statement - vulnerable to a LFI attack?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I'm thinking of including files into a script, that have names based on a cookie

Something like this:

```
include("sometext".$mycoockie_here."some_text.php");
```

Is the code above vulnerable to such attacks? - even with the `"sometext"` and `"sometex.php"` hard coded?

Comment: Just to prevent warnings, I'd call `file_exists()` first to make sure the resource exists before including it.  But the surrounding objects make it impossible for someone to do something like `include '/etc/passwd';`  For even more assurance, code a physical path in front of the filename so it can only come from one directory.

Comment: Just curious: Why you ask? If you proper validate your inputs, there will be no reasons to have any concerns. Don't trust _anything_!

Comment: @King: Very sensible advise :)

Comment: Well i was hoping to get off easy (without having to validate the cookie). But looks like thats not gonna happen now. Thanks for your answers guys! Appreciated.

Comment: @nav: it's really not that hard. Just do an `if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $mycookie_here)) exit();`

Comment: No upvotes for a reason,  you should have googled this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it is. Everyone can tweak the values of cookies send to your web application. Imagine someone sending you a cookie with the content

```
/../../../../etc/passwd[null-byte]
```

So you will end up with the path

```
sometext/../../../../etc/passwd[null-byte]some_test.php
```

The PHP file handling functions pass the path on to the OS, which uses null-terminated strings, so you will end up including the contents of

```
sometext/../../../../etc/passwd
```

Which you probably don't want.